# Can use 'in' with subqueries (like any/all)?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Can you pick up a result of subquery using IN instead of ANY?
I mean something like this:

`SELECT nazwisko FROM studenci WHERE rok_urodz > IN (SELECT rok_urodz FROM studenci WHERE miasto = "Warszawa");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not proper syntax, the comparison operator is only valid with ANY, SOME, and ALL.

If you replace 'IN' with 'ALL', this would also be OK syntax.  To use 'IN' you cannot include the comparison operator.

```
SELECT nazwisko 
FROM studenci 
WHERE rok_urodz IN (SELECT rok_urodz FROM studenci WHERE miasto = 'Warszawa');
```

is also acceptable syntax, but gives different results than

```
SELECT nazwisko 
FROM studenci 
WHERE rok_urodz > ALL (SELECT rok_urodz FROM studenci WHERE miasto = 'Warszawa');
```

IN is equivalent to = ANY

source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: Please note you should use single quotes, not double quotes, around `Warszawa`